# How to use `CONCAT` in a `UPDATE`

Tags: mysql

I´m trying to use `CONCAT` in a mysql `UPDATE`.

```
"INSERT INTO table ( 
   objekt_nr,
   objekt_status)
 VALUES(
  :objekt_nr,
  'salj,$fakt')

 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  objekt_status = VALUES(CONCAT(objekt_status, 'salj,$fakt'))";

 $query_params = array(
   ':objekt_nr' => $_POST['objekt_nr']);
```

I have tried several:

```
objekt_status = VALUES(CONCAT(objekt_status, objekt_status))";
objekt_status = VALUES(CONCAT(objekt_status, 'addMe'))";
objekt_status = VALUES(CONCAT(objekt_status, 'salj,$fakt'))";
objekt_status = VALUES((CONCAT(objekt_status, 'salj,$fakt')))";
```

Error Code for: 
    `objekt_status = VALUES(CONCAT(objekt_status, 'salj,$fakt'))";`
...syntax to use near '(objekt_status, 'salj,fakt,'))'

How should the code look like?

Comment: I think your code is incomplete, string arent floting on the air. And what is the problem do you have an error?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Updated!

Comment: What values you have in `$fakt`.

Comment: @AbhishekAgrawal You can see it in the error code. "fakt"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually in my case i needed the "Values" for every line but the CONCAT line.

```
objekt_created_when = VALUES(objekt_created_when),
objekt_status = CONCAT(objekt_status, 'salj,$fakt') ";
```

If i did remove VALUES from all rows, values in db, got empty!

Answer (score 3):

You have an semicolon where there should be a comma (after `VALUES(objekt_nr);`), and it appears the apostrophe is in the wrong place on the last line at `$fakt`. `VALUES` is only required for the `INSERT`, manual [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

This query should be correct:

```
"INSERT INTO table ( 
   objekt_nr,
   objekt_status)
 VALUES(
  :objekt_nr,
  'salj,$fakt')

 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  objekt_nr = objekt_nr,
  objekt_status = CONCAT(objekt_status, 'salj,$fakt')";
```

Also please ensure your variables are escaped, or use a prepared statement.

Comment: Sorry for the Semicolon, was only in this demo. But remove the Values seems to solved it. I have it on another query where i do not use CONCAT, and then it works.. Thank you.

Comment: Actually, I needed "VALUES" Because it was `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` if i don´t use it.. values was empty... BUT, on Concat, i removed VALUES and now it works fine!

Answer (score 1):

Try removing `values` as well as semicolon from the query

```
   "INSERT INTO table ( 
    objekt_nr,
    objekt_status)
    VALUES(
   :objekt_nr,
   'salj,$fakt')

    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    objekt_nr = objekt_nr,
    objekt_status = CONCAT(objekt_status, 'salj,'$fakt)";
```

Comment: Actually in my case i needed the "Values" for every line but the CONCAT line. If i did remove VALUES from all rows, values in db, got empty!